# Start service when the mobile is connected to the charger (ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED) in Android Oreo

Tags: java, android

I have problems when starting a service when the mobile is connected to the charger (ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED) in Android Oreo, by specifying it in the manifest with the receiver does not work (limitations android Oreo).
I've tried with JobSheduler, but I have not had a success (the service does not start when I connect the charger), my code is as follows:

```
public class JService extends JobService {
    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(final JobParameters jobParameters) {

        //RUN SERVICE

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(final JobParameters jobParameters) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And call from MainActivity (onCreate):

```
ComponentName myService = new ComponentName(this, JService.class);
    JobInfo myJob = new JobInfo.Builder(LOAD_ARTWORK_JOB_ID,myService)
            .setRequiresCharging(true)
            .setPersisted(true)
            .build();

    JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler) getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
    jobScheduler.schedule(myJob);
```

Mnifest declaration:

```
<service android:name=".services.JService"
             android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />
```

Comment: Note that your app needs the RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED permission for `setPersisted` to work.   



One more suggestion : try mentioning `com.yourpackagename.services.JService` instead of `.services.JService`

Comment: And what does `\\ Run Service` means?
    JobService itself is an service. It extends Service.

Look at  https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/job/JobService.java

Comment: I have tried to write the full name of the package and it does not work either, and it has the BOOT_COMPLETE permission. I know that extends service, start a service in the foreground.